# ¿Cómo acceder a una base de datos OOo desde HTML?

Tags: php, base-de-datos

En la oficina donde trabajo tengo que llevar una serie de indicadores y bases de datos.

Estas bases de datos no están automatizadas, y requieren que una persona las alimente.

Sin embargo, debido a las politicas de seguridad informatica, no tengo permiso de descargar **ninguna clase de software**.

Lo único que tengo es, aparte de exploradores de internet, LibreOffice 5.1, una carpeta compartida y notepad++.

En puntual, mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo puedo hacer que los usuarios (que tienen acceso a la carpeta compartida) puedan ingresar a la base de datos *a través de un sitio web local?***

Necesito esto porque es lo unico que se me ocurre para mantener protegida la integridad de la base de datos, pero no encuentro **NADA** en internet que pueda resolver esto.

**No puedo** utilizar:

- MySQL,
- PHP, ni
- Microsoft Office.

Ni nada más, en realidad. Sólo lo mencionado antes.

**edit1 - aclaración:**

Base de datos de LibreOffice Base (OOo).

No cuento con una máquina virtual ni con un servidor físico real.

La idea de esto es que se pueda encender y apagar según haga falta a voluntad de quien sea ADMIN en el momento (por ahora, yo).

Comment: Que base de datos usa? Si no puedes instalar ningun software creo que poco podras hacer. Tal vez con HTML y JavaScript podrias lograr pero deberias indicar mas datos sobre la base de datos, la manera en que se introducen los datos, si usan una web propia o algun programa interno.

Comment: Si no puedes usar php, deberias modificar los tags de la pregunta y añadir los lenguajes que si puedes usar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer es montarte una carpeta compartida con un codigo HTML y Javascrip(Jquery) si puedes, luego usar alguna de estas librerías que permiten agregar datos o modificar archivos xls.

si consigues esto podras hacer un formulario y cuando le den click en guardar o modificar ejecutar el jquery que agregue datos al xls.

Link de interes: 
[Link1](https://github.com/stephenliberty/excel-builder.js)
[Link2](http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/)
Activex Control [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382572/how-to-read-an-excel-file-contents-on-client-side)

Saludos

Comment: No puedo entrar a GitHub :(

Comment: tienes correo??

Comment: si, si tengo correo; pero no puedo entrar a github porque el sitio esta restringido aqui.

Comment: bueno estudiate en tu casa como hacer y que necesitas, documentas todo patra que sea algo persona, lo guardas en tu email y lo abres en tu trabajo...

Answer (score 0):

Si no puedes usar ningún lenguaje de lado de servidor, no se puede hacer lo que quieres lo único que se me ocurre es que desarrolles un programa en java y lo conectes  OOo, si tampoco puedes usar Java ps no hay forma de hacerlo y mi pésame por tener tantas restricciones.

Si te interesa hacerlo con java, puedes mirar este link:

http://java-estudio.blogspot.com.co/2013/09/como-conectar-desde-java-base-de-datos.html